# Running Pairs Trading Script

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the below script, but I keep getting the following error:
Error: unexpected string constant in ""Data" + Stock1 "+.l""

Here's my script so far:

```
Stock1 <- "PEP"
Stock2 <- "KO"
start.date <- "2014-01-01"
end.date <- Sys.Date()
Quote1 <- paste("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",
 Stock1,
 "&a=", substr(start.date,6,7),
 "&b=", substr(start.date, 9, 10),
 "&c=", substr(start.date, 1,4),
 "&d=", substr(end.date,6,7),
 "&e=", substr(end.date, 9, 10),
 "&f=", substr(end.date, 1,4),
 "&g=d&ignore=.csv", sep="")
Quote2 <- paste("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",
 Stock2,
 "&a=", substr(start.date,6,7),
 "&b=", substr(start.date, 9, 10),
 "&c=", substr(start.date, 1,4),
 "&d=", substr(end.date,6,7),
 "&e=", substr(end.date, 9, 10),
 "&f=", substr(end.date, 1,4),
 "&g=d&ignore=.csv", sep="")
"Data" + Stock1 "+.l" <- read.csv(Quote1, as.is=TRUE)
"Data" + Stock2 "+ .l" <- read.csv(Quote2, as.is=TRUE)
"X2=data" + Stock2 "+ ".l[order(data" + Stock2 + ".l$Date"),];Y2="data" + Stock1 "+ .l[order(data" + Stock1 + ".l$Date"),]

par(mfrow=c(1,1),fg = gray(0.7), bty="7")
plot(X2$Close,ylim=c(0,max(X2$Close)),ylab="Price",type="l")
lines(Y2$Close,col="red");grid()
lines(X2$Close/Y2$Close,col="green")

pairt=X2$Close/Y2$Close
abline(h=mean(pairt)+c(-2:2)*sd(pairt),col=c("black","purple"))
abline(h=mean(pairt),col="red")
```

So, I think there is something wrong with the concatenation of the string, but I'm not sure what the real issue is.  Also, is the concept, overall, sound?  Finally, is there a better way to do this, like dump in the S&P 500 tickers, get historical returns for around 2 years or so, and let R suggest the 'pairs', rather than let a human pair KO & PEP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is strange actually. The way you define `"Data" + Stock1 "+.l"`,`"Data" + Stock2 "+.l"` and `X1`,`X2` is not making sense (at least to me)

Once you define your quotes, I would change the code to the following:

```
Data1 <- read.csv(Quote1, as.is=TRUE)
Data2 <- read.csv(Quote2, as.is=TRUE)
X2=Data1[order(Data1$Date),];
Y2=Data2[order(Data2$Date),];

par(mfrow=c(1,1),fg = gray(0.7), bty="7")
plot(X2$Close,ylim=c(0,max(X2$Close)),ylab="Price",type="l")
lines(Y2$Close,col="red");grid()
lines(X2$Close/Y2$Close,col="green")
pairt=X2$Close/Y2$Close
abline(h=mean(pairt)+c(-2:2)*sd(pairt),col=c("black","purple"))
abline(h=mean(pairt),col="red")
```

which would have the following result:
[image]

I hope this helps

PS For pairs-trading you would need a bit of more-complex analysis than just returns comparison. Eg correlation, etc..

Comment: That works perfect.  Thanks so much.  Yes, it's very light.  Is there a good R-related site for learning more about this stuff?  I need a beginner level link.  I Googled for a bit, but didn't come up with much.

Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem. You could try http://quant.stackexchange.com/ for the mathematical background on pairs-trading(there are questions about this there) and if you want specific help on some issues, come back and ask here :)

Comment: If you found the answer to be correct, could you mark it as accepted so it closes the thread? :) Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  I just did it.  I've only been on SE for a few weeks, so I'm pretty new here.  

Last question.  How do I change the format to be more like a word processor?  Whenever I post something, everything gets concatenated together.  It's pretty annoying.

Thanks again.

Comment: For the comments there are not many things you can do, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting .It describes the markdown for the edits and posts :)